# Dealing with inserting noise to train data in Keras (Deep learning)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am using Keras for Deep learning.

I want to put noise into train data at each epoch during training.

So, at every epoch, the train data should be different from before epoch, because of random noise insertion.

This is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GaussianNoise(SNR_std))
model.add(Dense(neuron,input_dim=1920,
                kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(seed=seed_num),
                use_bias=False)
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Did I do it in a right way for my intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correct to me.

One thing to note is that if you change the images using noise like this you should visualize those images at least once before starting your training, so that you actually know what you are learning. So getting a handle to the output of that layer is key. Answers on how to do this can be found all over the internet: (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20469/keras-visualizing-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)